# Resampling a raster using rasterio - simple modification of grid spacing

Tags: python, geopandas, rasterio

I am resampling raster data using Python's rasterio. Looking at the `rasterio.enums.Resampling` class, it appears the only way to do this is to interpolate between adjacent raster grids, essentially smoothing the data.

Is there some way to do a simple upsampling that effectively divides one raster grid into many and preserves the original value for all of the sub-grids?

My resampling script is as follows - currently using the bi-linear method:

```
with rasterio.open(str(rasterpath+filename), crs="EPSG:4326") as src:
    data = src.read(
        out_shape=(
            src.count,
            int(src.height * upscale_factor),
            int(src.width * upscale_factor)
        ),
        resampling=Resampling.bilinear)

# scale image transform
    transform = src.transform * src.transform.scale(
        (src.width / data.shape[-1]),
        (src.height / data.shape[-2])
    )
```

Any suggestions? I would think some sort of treatment for discrete data would be built in but have not found it yet...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a solution.

Deleting `resampling=Resampling.bilinear` avoids interpolation and performs a "simple" resampling.

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to do is nearest neighbor interpolation, so you could specify `resampling = Resampling.nearest`. This is the default resampling algorithm, so not specifying any resampling algorithm equates to this. You can find all available resampling algorithms [here](https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/rasterio.enums.html#rasterio.enums.Resampling).